# Information going out from my machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I am installing a software via an msi file (web installer too). I want to find out all the data that this installer retrieves from my machine (like OS type, IP address, MAC address etc) while installation and sends it to its server.

Do you know of any monitoring tool that will show what data flows out of my network to their servers. I am using a desktop which is not connected to any other machine,.

Answer (score 0):

[Net Limiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) does this pretty well. It is very similar to little snitch, and will tell you if/when an installer connects to a server. It doesn't show what it sends, but you can wait to send the data, until you snoop around a little bit. Also you can try IP Traffic Spy, more info [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/monitor-incoming-and-outgoing-network-traffic-with-ip-traffic-spy/). It will show what is being sent.

Comment: The tool looks good but I need to see what data does this installer send to it's server. It's my machine and my internet, isn't there any way I can find out what's going out of my machine?

Comment: @user195668 read this about using ip traffic spy, it explains it pretty well, and you can view the data.

Comment: this looks good mate. I will try it and post my observations here. Thanks for the tip!